# How can I calculate the sell through rate of items sold through an online store?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Using Excel, I want to get a visual of how quickly products sell out when compared to other products. In essence, how many days does it take to sell 100 items of Product A vs 100 items of Product B.

To do this, we have an order export from our Shopify store. The data has one product name per row, showing the quantity ordered and the date it was purchased.

I've tried working with pivot tables and am having a hard time understanding how to manipulate the data to get what I want.

[Here's a link to some sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10wyg2PxFSKz6j367gpycndZKYo5gZMQEtyAg6yE8hmw/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Sampla data]

In my mind, there would be a graph with the x-axis being the number of days the item is sold, the y-axis is the quantity sold, and there is a plotted line for each product (with the ability to select/unselect the product as we have many.) As an aside, not all products begin selling on the same date so we can't just start looking at January 1 and see which product hits 100 sells first.

It would also be incredible to have a table showing all the products and how many days it takes to sell 100 of each product.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Instead of posting a link to sample data please include a sample directly in your question. This site is designed to capture questions and their answers such that you *and* others with the same question can benefit.

Comment: I cannot open your sample data.  Says the file is corrupt or the extension does not match the file

Comment: I moved it from Dropbox to Google Sheets. Please try again. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered just displaying the actual number of days per 100 for each product?  You've got quantity and days for that quantity.  `100*Days/Quantity` is the days per 100.  You can plot that if you want a visual, and it won't require interpreting data with different start dates, durations, or slopes of lines.

Comment: I think I'm getting what you're saying but I'm not totally sure how I would get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to display is how many days it takes to sell 100 items for each product.  Trying to do this with a graph of the raw data isn't a good approach for that when you can directly calculate the number.  If you want something more visual, you can always graph those resulting numbers.  So let's start with the table you mention at the end of the question, which can be the source for other types of displays.

The days per 100 can be found with the formula `100*Days/Quantity`.  Consider an example where you sell 50 units in 10 days.  Dividing 10 days by 50 units tells you that it takes on average 1/5 of a day per unit.  So to sell 100 units would take 20 days.

You can use a pivot table to do the heavy lifting.  That will summarize the data by Product, summing the quantities, and identifying the date range associated with those quantities.  Dates are stored in units of days, so subtracting dates gives you the difference in days.  The data and pivot table look like this:

[image]

I added a helper column to the right of the pivot table for the calculated Days/100.  It just references values in the pivot table.  The formula in J2:

```
= 100*(1+I2-H2)/G2
```

Subtracting the start date from the end date excludes one endpoint, so I added `1`.  The Min and Max functions are pivot table options for the type of aggregation to perform on the date values.  I formatted the dates in the pivot table as dates for readability since the pivot table wanted to display them as raw day counts, the way they are stored internally.

Once the pivot table is created, you can hide the columns with the intermediate values you don't need to see.  Hiding columns G:I will give you a list of the products and their days to sell 100.  If you want to see that in a graph, there are a number of basic chart types that will stack the product names and position markers proportional to their days/100 values.

Comment: This is a great workaround. I think I can use it to go even further. Thanks for the time on this!